# asp.net webforms vs mvc which is best for business applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, webforms

`Diamonds` is an ERP based on windows forms, I'm going to redevelop it using web technologies rather than Windows Forms ..

but now I need to decide which is best for this, the `ASP.NET webforms` (as i think) is easier to (design) i mean here the UI, but the `mvc` has simpler html output, and some other features ...

can you help me decide which technology to use and why ?

I'm using C#,

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think both technologies can get a bit complicated after getting past any of the basics. Here are some brief opinions that I gathered while having to implement a project that must live in both MVC and WebForms hosts.

WebForms Positives:

1. The maturity of the product
2. Lots of 3rd party support with regard to sophisticated controls
3. There are ways to get around the legacy-feeling aspects of the framework (e.g., [WebForms MVP](http://webformsmvp.com/))

WebForms Negatives:

1. Page lifecycle issues can anger you to no end; there are a lot of moving parts to a sophisticated web application
2. Using dependency injection is "difficult" to use/implement
3. There is a lot in the framework that you can't control
4. Need something like Reflector to dive into decompiled source when have questions that are not answered by documentation, web, experimentation.

MVC Positives:

1. Great separation of concerns and support of dependency injection
2. More control over so many things (i.e., project structure, mvc framework, rendered content, etc)
3. You can xcopy deploy your app along with the mvc framework on top of an asp.net 4 installation (i.e., to a 3rd party hosting provider)
4. Native support of JSON
5. Source code (w/ comments!!) provided so that you can dive into various features when you run into questions on the internals.
6. They've been doing out-of-band releases on tooling and I believe plan to do so on the framework (?); they have a futures project along with the source that shows you some of the directions they are going and which you could make use of if you should choose to.

MVC Negatives:

1. Can take a little time to wrap one's mind around
2. Not as many 3rd party helpers (no controls); those that exist seem to be not as sophisticated as their WebForm counterparts

Personally, I'm an MVC fan because of the control, flexibility, and transparent dependency injection support.  Perhaps you should do a small pilot with both technologies to see which one you prefer. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: "Using dependency injection is "difficult" to use/implement" - How so? Injecting dependencies into `Page`'s is remarkable easy and similar to setting up a controller factory  http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ioc_and_di_with_web_forms

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me, using nuget to "install" ninject into my mvc project (which then uses the WebActivator to seamlessly inject dependencies into my controllers) is more intuitive than implementing a custom PageHandlerFactory. I have a solution that partially runs in mvc and partially in webforms, and I ended up using a ServiceLocator pattern for webforms. I cannot change the base class to my controls/pages, and I wanted to keep it simple. One definitely can get it to work, but I found MVC easier to set up.

Comment: @Jason - There is a Ninject nuget package for webforms.  Don't see how this is different or more intuitive from MVC.

Comment: Hi @Jfar, yes there is, but it had the pages/controls must inherit requirement. I was/am new to ninject and DI in an ASP.NET host, so it could be that I couldn't wrap my mind around it. Webforms is a great tech. As a Ninject noob, I just found MVC easier for me to get setup and running wrt DI. Which makes sense to me, as it was designed with that in mind. (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html)

Comment: @Jason, your answer is great, but i need one more clarification, I used to use the Event Driven Lifecycle in the webforms, is that simple enough in MVC, if you could give me some tutorials, this gonna help ;

Cheers

Comment: @Mustafa, awesome! MVC is completely different from the event driven model. You basically create an action link on your webpage (view) and maps to an action on a controller. Best thing to do would be check out the tutorials on asp.net site. http://www.asp.net/mvc That was the most helpful to me (esp creating a small app). Also, look for items by Scott Hanselman. Finally, be sure you're using mvc v3. It's not installed on VS2010 by default (as it was released post-vs2010), so you will have to download and install.

Comment: @Mustafa, ps: Be sure to try the Razor view engine. I really have enjoyed using/ learning that.

Answer (score 6):

If you care about extensibility, ease of maintenance, scalability and robustness of your application, as well as development of your software development skills, then stay as far away as possible from web forms.

The whole idea of adding a layer of state by wrapping everything in a form is just wrong. HTTP is stateless, and MVC is built around that model, which is good.

**Edit**
In regards to the comments made. Web forms applications are not extensible because presentation layer, business logic and data access code (data sources) all reside in code behind. Controls that are offered by web forms are applicable only in web forms. This means that you won't be able to transfer these skills to another web development framework.

Finally, of course it is possible to write a tightly coupled application using MVC - there is always a way to destroy something. There is no argument about that. The main point is that MVC encourages a seperation of concerns and single responsibility principle, when web forms practically takes it away from you.

You have also said that web forms is easier. It's easier if you have been using it and it's faster to pick up in comparison to MVC, however, in a long-term run MVC is likely to become "easier". Watch few videos on www.asp.net/mvc. Additionally you might want to look into test-driven development (unit-testing). I don't think that unit testing works with web forms because everything is so tightly coupled. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

I would be very interested to hear opinions of other developers who have experience of working with both frameworks.

Comment: This answer is spot on. You will see people supporting both sides of the argument, but as a long time webforms dev who recently dove head first into MVC, I can honestly say I never want to write another web forms app again :)

Comment: IMHO MVC is clearly better but all the reasons you cite have nothing to do with the underlying framework but rather are gained from the quality of code delivered by developers.  Scalability also sticks out as having nothing to do with the web front end but is always dependent on the underlying data services.  A MVC site with an overloaded db is just as slow as a webforms database.

Comment: @vikp - "Web forms applications are not extensible because presentation layer, business logic and data access code (data sources) all reside in code behind"  - No, thats totally wrong.  That is all based on how the application is coded and you could just as easily have all this type of code inside your controller.

Comment: @vikp  - "MVC encourages a seperation of concerns and single responsibility principle, when web forms practically takes it away from you." - What?  How does webforms take away SOC and SRP?  I've seen plenty of good webforms code that looks very similar to any well constructed controller.

Comment: @vikp - I am all about MVC too...but your answer is full of misconceptions as jfar points out...

Comment: Can you give some examples please?

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend MVC simply because once the UI is ironed out, it makes development so much easier from a back-end viewpoint. There are TONS of mvc vs asp questions out there:
[1](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2010/03/11/webforms-vs-mvc-again/),
[2](http://blog.gadodia.net/choosing-between-webforms-and-mvc/),
[3](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http://weblogs.asp.net/despos/archive/2009/04/11/web-forms-vs-asp-net-mvc.aspx&rct=j&q=web%20forms%20vs%20mvc&ei=QgHyTYaZDefx0gH_0LWKDA&usg=AFQjCNGXXvH7rF1o5p_UCXhSpOFmlUu0Og&cad=rja)

From my perspective MVC wins based solely on TDD and no Viewstate. But it really depends on how you plan to manage and use the various features of either.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this post from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/24/about-technical-debates-both-in-general-and-regarding-asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-in-particular.aspx) is really interesting to read. After reading, I think you'll most likely go for ASP.NET MVC. :-)

Answer (score 1):

While I have done plenty of projects with web forms, I have to say that the primary reason they exist is to provide a layer of abstraction over HTTP, largely to facilitate an event-based model on a stateless protocol.  Unfortunately, like most MS solutions, that comes at a price.

Historically, web forms used to be plagued with issues around the generation of markup.  Some of these issues still persist today, especially when it comes to ViewState.  Things are slightly better now( you can manage the DOM id in ASP .NET 4.0 ) but web forms will still cause you grief.  Common things you'll see in web form projects are vast amounts of biz logic squirreled away in codebehind.

MVC doesn't eliminate this, but it provides a structure and separation of concerns that makes bad practice less likely.  That said, although the default view engine is better at producing clean markup from an end-user perspective, the inline code in views is a throwback to classic ASP.

For what it's worth, I've stopped developing web form projects and have moved exclusively to MVC for new work.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO MVC

I had to write a report to justify changing to MVC from Web Forms/Nettiers

I blogged my arguments [here](http://ivida.co.uk/2011/05/11/mvc-nhibernate-vs-webforms-nettiers/)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about your choice having Web Forms can give you easy of designing your app where as MVC is now days becoming industry standard and even MS is promoting it a lot. If you want to keep your code clean then no doubt MVC is better choice.